# Are there any good database management applications for JDBC/Java databases?

Tags: management, derby, jdbc

I am working with an Apache Derby/JavaDB database via JDBC. Before have I been working with MySQL and used phpMyAdmin as a good Database Management tool.

Is there any good desktop application for managing databases over JDBC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DbVisualiser](http://www.dbvis.com/) could fulfill your requirements as it supports [quite a number of RDBMS](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/features/index.jsp?feature=2), including JavaDB/Derby. You can see it in action below: [image: manager]

The only question mark is if the free version has some limitations which are a stopper for you. You can check the matrix [here](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/features/index.jsp?page=matrix).